# Javascript math operation outcome

Tags: javascript

This very simple math operation is confusing me..

```
var cap = '17.00'
var amount = '114.00';

if(amount > cap){
    alert('Greater');
}else{
     alert('Less Than');   
}
```

Why would this result say `114.00` is less than `17.00` ?

I'm sure its a very straight forward answer. These are both integers so I figured it would be a straight comparison of the values but apparently I am wrong?

Comment: There is no integer in your code. First of all, they are Strings. Second, if you remove the `'`s, they are still not integers because of the `.00`. Third, they are still not integer because all numbers in JavaScript are Doubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not saying that `114.00` is less than `17.00`, it's saying that `"114.00"` comes before `"17.00"`.

You are comparing strings, so the comparison is done according to how the strings would be sorted, not what numerical value they represent.

If you want to compare numbers, you need to put numbers in the variables:

```
var cap = 17.00;
var amount = 114.00;
```

Answer (score 2):

> These are both integers so I figured it would be a straight comparison of the values

That's the problem: they're not integers, they're strings. Strings are compared lexicographically, e.g. `('a' < 'b') === true` and `('a' < 'aaa') === true`.

If you want to compare them as numbers, make sure they're numbers to begin with:

```
var cap = 17.00; // the .00 is redundant though, just 17 would also work
var amount = 114.00;
```

or if those variables are received as strings from elsewhere, convert them first:

```
var cap = '17.00';
var amount = '114.00';
if (Number(cap) < Number(amount)){
    alert('Greater');
}else{
     alert('Less Than');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes surrounding the numbers. You're comparing strings instead of numbers.